# PDO with memsql

Tags: php, pdo, singlestore

Hello I'm trying to connect php 7 so mysql PDO driver with memsql (supposed to be fully compliant) the probleme is that the dsn string seems to be not correctly interpreted the error is "no database selected" despite I give the dbname=xxx in the dsn string could you help ?

```
        $first_dsn = 'mysql:host=192.168.132.131;port:3307;dbname=cerf;charset=utf8';
        $second_dsn = 'mysql:host=192.168.132.132;port:3307;dbname=cerf;charset=utf8';

        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';

        ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        //echo phpinfo();

        try {
            //$db = new DB($first_dsn, $username, $password, $second_dsn);
            $db = new PDO($first_dsn, $username, $password);

            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES UTF8');
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }



        try {
            //$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `prospects` ORDER BY `id_prospects` LIMIT 20");
            $db->exec("use cerf");
            if (!$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `prospects` ORDER BY `id_prospects` LIMIT 20")) {
                die(var_export($db->errorinfo(), TRUE));
            }
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }

        if ($stmt != FALSE) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo 'id : ' . $row['id_prospects'] . ' - ' . $row['raison_sociale'] . '<br />';
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('/!\Erreur pdo statement return false');
        }
```

the error is "no database selected" I don't understand why
Thx for your help

Comment: What if you explicitly execute `USE databasename`?

Comment: same result ...

Comment: Can you edit your question with the added code specifying the database?

Comment: it may be not the issue, but what you you thinking of posting the question about DSN but not providing the DSN you are using?

Comment: Here is my dsn I just did not give it here

Comment: Looks like there is no such database like cerf

Comment: I've restarted my apache2 and it works... now if I specify 127.0.0.1 on my dsn it works but if I write 192.168.132.131 it fails "Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.132.131' (using password: YES)"